# How to read and write a file in java using buffered reader and bufferedwriter

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I need to read a file and write into a separate file. I must also be able to read two files and write them into a single file.

```
File 1(To be read)
Header
text 
text
Footer

File 2(To be read)
Header
Text12
Text12
Footer

Output file

Header
text
text
Text12
Text12
Footer
```

the first line and last line remains same but only the middle lines are appended.
According to my code. The header and footer is appended twice.

```
My output :
Header
text 
text
Footer
Header
Text12
Text12
Footer



My Code :

for (int i = 0; i < template.length; i++) {


        String endTime = findEndTime(startTime, duration);

        File file = new File(foldername);
        file.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                foldername + "/" + solfilename, true));
        BufferedWriter bsftp = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "c:/ToolSOlFile/" + solfilename, true));


        try {
            String verify, putData = null,header=null,footer=null;

            FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/ToolSOlFile/Templates/"+ template[i]);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((verify = br.readLine()) != null) { 


                    putData = verify.replace("YYYYMMDD", yyyymmdd);

                    putData = putData.replace("DD", duration);


                    putData = putData.replace("IIIIIIIIIIIIIII", imsi);


                    putData = putData.replace("HHMMSS", startTime);

                    putData = putData.replace("hhmmss", endTime);

                    putData = putData.replace("XXXXXXXXX", msisdn);

                    putData = putData.replace("BBBBBBBBBBBBBB",
                            processor.returnTemplateName(template[i]));


                    bw.append(putData + "\n");
                    bsftp.append(putData + "\n");

                }


            }

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();

            bsftp.flush();
            bsftp.close();
            br.close();

            startTime = findUpdatedStartTime(startTime);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code

Comment: read footer only from first file, store it in String and write at last. read header from first file only

Comment: @user7 code attached

Comment: you are not using header and footer variable. assign them value and use only once while writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code given below it should help you to identify header footer and middle lines, then u can play around and write them into a file as u wish

try {

```
                reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String next, line = reader.readLine();
                for (boolean first = true, last = (line == null); !last; first = false, line = next) {
                    last = ((next = reader.readLine()) == null);


                    if (first) {

                        header=line;
                        System.out.println("First Line : "+header);


                    } else if (last) {

                        footer=line;
                        System.out.println("Middle Line : "+footer);



                    } else {

                        middle=line;
                        System.out.println("Footer Line : "+middle);



                    }

                    //WriteBUlkFileWithDifferenttemplates(header,middle,footer);

                }System.out.println("\n \n");
            } finally {
                if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
            }





        }
```